# Add distinct within json_agg

Tags: json, postgresql, postgresql-12

I have the following sample data:

--EmpMap:

```
create table EmpMap 
(
   id int
);

insert into EmpMap values(1),(2),(3);
```

--EmpInfo:

```
create table EmpInfo
(
    empid int,
    empname varchar
);

insert into empinfo values(1,'Mak'),(2,'Jack'),(3,'John');
```

--EmpAdd:

```
create table EmpAdd
(
   EmpID int,
   Address varchar
);

insert into EmpAdd values(1,'Addr1'),(1,'Addr1'),(1,'Addr1'),(2,'Add2'),(3,'Add3'),(2,'Add2');
```

**Query**:

```
select e.ID,
       count(1) as Counts,
       json_agg
       (
            json_build_object
            (
            'EmpID',ei.EmpID,
            'EmpAdd',ea.address
            )
       ) as emp_json_address
from empmap e
join EmpInfo ei on e.id = ei.empid
join empadd ea on ei.empid = ea.empid
group by e.ID;
```

**Output**:

```
id|counts|emp_json_address                                                                                         |
--|------|---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
 1|     3|[{"EmpID" : 1, "EmpAdd" : "Addr1"}, {"EmpID" : 1, "EmpAdd" : "Addr1"}, {"EmpID" : 1, "EmpAdd" : "Addr1"}]|
 2|     2|[{"EmpID" : 2, "EmpAdd" : "Add2"}, {"EmpID" : 2, "EmpAdd" : "Add2"}]                                     |
 3|     2|[{"EmpID" : 3, "EmpAdd" : "Address3"}, {"EmpID" : 3, "EmpAdd" : "Add3"}]                                                                       |
```

**Expected Output**:

```
id|counts|emp_json_address                                                              |
--|------|------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
 1|     1|[{"EmpID" : 1, "EmpAdd" : "Addr1"}]                                           |
 2|     1|[{"EmpID" : 2, "EmpAdd" : "Add2"}]                                            |
 3|     2|[[{"EmpID" : 3, "EmpAdd" : "Address3"}, {"EmpID" : 3, "EmpAdd" : "Add3"}]     |
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's what the `DISTINCT` keyword in aggregate functions is for:

```
json_agg (DISTINCT
   jsonb_build_object (...)
)
```

Then duplicate entries will be removed.

Note: you have to use `jsonb_build_object` rather than `json_build_object`, because the is no equality operator for `json`.

Comment: I don't think `DISTINCT` work with `json_build_object`.

Comment: Getting an error: `SQL Error [42883]: ERROR: could not identify an equality operator for type json`

Comment: Oops, you were right, fixed. You have to use `jsonb_build_object`.

Answer (score 0):

The json part has nothing to do with this.

Also, your outputs do not match what you added in the EmpAdd part.

Add `ea.address` to the `group by`.

```
select e.ID,
       count(1) as Counts,
       json_agg
       (
            json_build_object
            (
            'EmpID',ei.EmpID,
            'EmpAdd',ea.address
            )
       ) as emp_json_address
from empmap e
join EmpInfo ei on e.id = ei.empid
join empadd ea on ei.empid = ea.empid
group by e.ID, ea.address;
```